# CosmoDb BulkImporter throws InvalidPartitionException

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

while importing data into cosmodb at a rate of 5000 docs/second, we got this exception

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.InvalidPartitionException: Partition range id 0 does not exist, please retry shortly after re-initializing BulkExecutor instance, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0
```

The code we use is below

```
response =  await _bulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(data, true);
```

where data is and object array and they all have the partion key value.

Do you know what happens and why the exception was thrown. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hit a same issue as you. It should be caused by partition split. When your partition is approaching 10GB storage limitation, the partition will be split and looks like the original partition id is not valid, but the bulk executor doesn't refresh this partition map. You can try add a logic to catch such exception and re-initialize your bulk Executor.